# Obtain javafx controls from Map declared in fxml

Tags: java, xml, javafx, collections

I know the way I can put some of my javafx controls into and ArrayList, like:

```
//FXML file
<Label fx:id="label1"/>
<Label fx:id="label2"/>
<fx:define>
    <ArrayList fx:id="list">
        <fx:reference souce="label1"/>
        <fx:reference souce="label2"/>
    </ArrayList>
</fx:define>

//Controller class
public class Controller{
    @FXML 
    private ArrayList<Label> list;
}
```

These 2 labels are stored in my list (without necessarity to declare them separately as fields). Is there any way to define in fxml file a Map (for example TreeMap) and if it is, how to do that properly? I'd like to define a Map, which keys are elements of my enumeration, and values are Labels, for instance, and the only @FXML field I'd like to see in my controller class is this Map.

Comment: AFAIK it is only possible to fill a `Map` with `String` keys.

Comment: In this case, how should the fxml file look like?

Comment: `<TreeMap fx:id="map"><key1><fx:reference souce="label1"/></key1><key2><fx:reference souce="label2"/></key2></TreeMap>`